# Generics doesn't work for return type

Tags: java, enums

How come java doesn't allow the following generic return type:

```
public <T extends Enum<T> & MyInterface> Class<T> getEnum() {
    return MyEnum.class;
}
```

While the following does work:

```
public <T extends Enum<T> & MyInterface> Class<T> getEnum(Class<T> t) {
    return t;
}

getEnum(MyEnum.class);
```

`MyEnum` is an enumaration that implements the interface `MyInterface`.

Why am I not allowed to return `MyEnum.class`?

EDIT:

I need this because the function `getEnum()` is in an interface. It could be defined as follows:

```
@Override
public Class<MyEnum> getEnum() {
    return MyEnum.class;
}
```

But what would then then be the return type of the interface method to allow any `Class` object of a class that is both an enum and implements `MyInterface`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your method is parameterized by `T` - the idea is that the *caller* gets to specify what `T` is - not the method implementation.

The call to the second method works because `T` is implicitly specified (by the caller) to be `MyEnum`.

Comment: Ah yes, that makes sense, how would I go about saying I want the function to return a `Class` of an object that is both and enum and implements `MyInterface`. (I'll update my question to reflect why I want this)

Answer (score 2):

I've found the answer to my second question too:

The interface with the generic type needs to be parameterized:

```
public interface MyEnumReturner <T extends Enum<T> & MyInterface>
{
    public Class<T> getEnum(Class<T> t);
}
```

Then the class implementing the interface defines which type to use:

```
public class MyClass implments MyEnumReturner<MyEnum>
{
    @Override
    public Class<MyEnum> getEnum() {
        return MyEnum.class;
    }

}
```